# Dynamic SQL query string truncated to 256 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to run dynamic SQL in  SQL Server 2016, like this:

```
 declare @SQL varchar(MAX);

 set @SQL='SELECT top 1 * INTO Table 1 FROM 
 OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', etc... (string aprox. 450 char)

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

For some reason, the variable @SQL is truncated to 256 characters. I already followed instructions in the article below and modify some SQL Server query settings but no result. See:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2795/prevent-truncation-of-dynamically-generated-results-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Can you please advise, not sure what I am missing, it didn't happen in SQL Server 2008 that I used before. is there any additional setting in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: `sp_executesql` uses `nvarchar`, you should declare `@sql` as such, and also `SET @sql = N'....`

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution! How can I mark the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `sp_executesql` uses `nvarchar`, so you should declare `@sql` as such, and also `SET @sql = N'....`:

```
 DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

 SET @SQL = N'SELECT top 1 * INTO Table 1 FROM 
 OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', etc... '

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```